# pyspark - merge 2 columns of sets

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe that has 2 columns formed from the function collect_set. I would like to combine these 2 columns of sets into 1 column of set. How should I do so? They are both set of strings

For Instance I have 2 columns formed from calling collect_set

```
Fruits                  |    Meat
[Apple,Orange,Pear]          [Beef, Chicken, Pork]
```

How do I turn it into:

```
Food

[Apple,Orange,Pear, Beef, Chicken, Pork]
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance

Comment: Please provide more information like structure of the dataframe with examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `df` has

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|              Fruits|                Meat|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[Pear, Orange, Ap...|[Chicken, Pork, B...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

then

```py
import itertools
df.rdd.map(lambda x: [item for item in itertools.chain(x.Fruits, x.Meat)]).collect()
```

creates a set of `Fruits` & `Meat` combined into one set i.e.

```
[[u'Pear', u'Orange', u'Apple', u'Chicken', u'Pork', u'Beef']]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

I was also figuring this out in Python, so here is a port of Ramesh's solution to Python:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(['Pear','Orange','Apple'], ['Chicken','Pork','Beef'])],
                           ("Fruits", "Meat"))
df.show(1,False)

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
mergeCols = udf(lambda fruits, meat: fruits + meat)
df.withColumn("Food", mergeCols(col("Fruits"), col("Meat"))).show(1,False)
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|Fruits               |Meat                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
|[Pear, Orange, Apple]|[Chicken, Pork, Beef]|
+---------------------+---------------------+
+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|Fruits               |Meat                 |Food                                      |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|[Pear, Orange, Apple]|[Chicken, Pork, Beef]|[Pear, Orange, Apple, Chicken, Pork, Beef]|
+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Kudos to Ramesh!

---

*EDIT:* Note that you might have to manually specify the column type (not sure why it worked for me only in some cases without explicit type specification - in other cases I was getting a string type column).

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
mergeCols = udf(lambda fruits, meat: fruits + meat, ArrayType(StringType()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have `dataframe` as

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|Fruits               |Meat                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
|[Pear, Orange, Apple]|[Chicken, Pork, Beef]|
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

You can write a `udf` function to merge the sets of two columns into one.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def mergeCols = udf((fruits: mutable.WrappedArray[String], meat: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => fruits ++ meat)
```

And then call the `udf` function as

```scala
df.withColumn("Food", mergeCols(col("Fruits"), col("Meat"))).show(false)
```

You should have your desired final `dataframe`

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|Fruits               |Meat                 |Food                                      |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|[Pear, Orange, Apple]|[Chicken, Pork, Beef]|[Pear, Orange, Apple, Chicken, Pork, Beef]|
+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is this with python? I can't seem to find mutable.WrappedArray

Comment: this is all in scala :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding solution here for the definition of a set not containing duplicates. Also avoids any performance concerns with python udfs.

Requires Spark 2.4+

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(['Chicken','Pork','Beef',"Tuna"], ["Salmon", "Tuna"])],
                           ("Meat", "Fish"))
df.show(1,False)
df_union = df.withColumn("set_union", F.array_distinct(F.array_union("Meat", "Fish")))
df_union.show(1, False)
```

results in

```
+---------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
|Meat                       |Fish          |set_union                          |
+---------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
|[Chicken, Pork, Beef, Tuna]|[Salmon, Tuna]|[Chicken, Pork, Beef, Tuna, Salmon]|
+---------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
```